# create invoice from order XAF

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, xaf

I am trying to create an invoice from an order in XAF.
I follow the [Add an Action that Displays a Pop-up Window from the devexpress web site](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument112723)

Using a View controller and an Action
I have an order class and order_Details class as a Collection of orders with an Invoice class and Invoice_Data class as a collection of Invoice

```
  Private Sub Create_Invoice_Action_CustomizePopupWindowParams(sender As Object, e As CustomizePopupWindowParamsEventArgs) Handles Create_Invoice_Action.CustomizePopupWindowParams
        Dim objectSpace As IObjectSpace = Application.CreateObjectSpace()
        e.View = Application.CreateListView(Application.FindListViewId(GetType(elmts.OrderDetail)), _
        New CollectionSource(objectSpace, GetType(elmts.OrderDetail)), True)

    End Sub

    Private Sub ShowNotesAction_Execute(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As PopupWindowShowActionExecuteEventArgs) Handles Create_Invoice_Action.Execute


        Dim _invoiceDetails As elmts.InvoiceData = CType(View.CurrentObject, elmts.InvoiceData)
        View.ObjectSpace.SetModified(_invoiceDetails)
        For Each _nv_Det As elmts.OrderDetail In e.PopupWindow.View.SelectedObjects
            If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(_invoiceDetails.ProductName)) Then
                _invoiceDetails.ProductName += Environment.NewLine
            End If
            _invoiceDetails.ProductName += _nv_Det.Division
        Next _nv_Det
        Dim item As ViewItem = (CType(View, DetailView)).FindItem("ProductName")
        CType(item, PropertyEditor).ReadValue()
        'Save changes to the database if the current Detail View is displayed in the View mode 
        If TypeOf View Is DetailView AndAlso (CType(View, DetailView)).ViewEditMode = _
            ViewEditMode.View Then
            View.ObjectSpace.CommitChanges()
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub PopupNotesController_Activated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Activated
        Create_Invoice_Action.Active.SetItemValue("ObjectType", DirectCast(View, DetailView).ObjectTypeInfo.Type Is GetType(elmts.Order))
    End Sub​
```

Another words I like to from the Order detailView  with an OrderDetailsCollection view add an action that will

1. Create the new Invoice and Commit the changes to the database
2. grab the Oder.OrderDetail Collection currentview items and pass them to  the Newly created Invoice.InvoiceData Collection
3. Set the Order as Invoiced

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Did the action button showed? Action click error? Nothing happens at all? :)

Comment: Thanks ErikWitkowski yes it showed and the popupwindow shows me the list, when clicking the ok button I get the following error A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in elmts.Module.dll

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'elmts.Module.elmts.Order' to type 'elmts.Module.elmts.InvoiceData'.

Comment: can I show you another piece of code with a link to it? I first ask because I don't want to confuse anyone, but it may help with what I want to accomplished, Again thanks for your help

Comment: Isn't it because View.CurrentObject is of Type 'elmts.Module.elmts.Order' when you expect 'elmts.Module.elmts.InvoiceData'? Please set the controller TargetObjectType = typeof(elmts.Module.elmts.InvoiceData) to make sure.

Comment: I try that already but then the action wont be visible from the orderDetailView  and that's from where it shoul be done, Im posting the link I spoke of before [Link](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q576083)

Comment: Ok, instead of change TargetObjectType, just keep in mind that in ShowNotesAction_Execute, that you will get an Order as the View.CurrentObject.

Comment: Dim _order As elmts.Order = CType(View.CurrentObject, elmts.Order);

 Dim _invoiceDetails As elmts.InvoiceData = _order.Invoice; << Not sure about the property path.

Comment: I see this here on the page  
Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?  I cant do it because I have only 3 points according to the message I received when I click the link

Comment: Hello Erik again and Thank you for all of your help, you know I've never ask many question in the forums cause I always tough no one really care but you've proof me wrong, ok so did you by any chance look at the link 4 post back?

Comment: I didn't dig into your support ticket details, but the error you are facing right now looks very simple to solve. Since stackoverflow doens't have a good way to send private messages, I've added a answer so we can keep this going.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
Private Sub Create_Invoice_Action_CustomizePopupWindowParams(sender As Object, e As CustomizePopupWindowParamsEventArgs) Handles Create_Invoice_Action.CustomizePopupWindowParams
    Dim objectSpace As IObjectSpace = Application.CreateObjectSpace()
    e.View = Application.CreateListView(Application.FindListViewId(GetType(elmts.OrderDetail)), _
    New CollectionSource(objectSpace, GetType(elmts.OrderDetail)), True)

End Sub

Private Sub ShowNotesAction_Execute(ByVal sender As Object, _ByVal e As PopupWindowShowActionExecuteEventArgs) Handles Create_Invoice_Action.Execute
    'Dim _invoiceDetails As elmts.InvoiceData = CType(View.CurrentObject, elmts.InvoiceData) << Wrong, since View.CurrentObject is elmts.Order
    Dim _order As elmts.Order = CType(View.CurrentObject, elmts.Order); 
    Dim _invoiceDetails As elmts.InvoiceData = _order.CreateInvoice(); 'creates a new InvoiceData

    View.ObjectSpace.SetModified(_invoiceDetails)
    For Each _nv_Det As elmts.OrderDetail In e.PopupWindow.View.SelectedObjects
        If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(_invoiceDetails.ProductName)) Then
            _invoiceDetails.ProductName += Environment.NewLine
        End If
        _invoiceDetails.ProductName += _nv_Det.Division
    Next _nv_Det
    Dim item As ViewItem = (CType(View, DetailView)).FindItem("ProductName")
    CType(item, PropertyEditor).ReadValue()
    'Save changes to the database if the current Detail View is displayed in the View mode 
    If TypeOf View Is DetailView AndAlso (CType(View, DetailView)).ViewEditMode = _
        ViewEditMode.View Then
        View.ObjectSpace.CommitChanges()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub PopupNotesController_Activated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Activated
    Create_Invoice_Action.Active.SetItemValue("ObjectType", DirectCast(View, DetailView).ObjectTypeInfo.Type Is GetType(elmts.Order))
End Sub​
```

Comment: let me check this out and ill let you know

Comment: Thanks again and sorry I took so long to answer, but how will I get the Invoice reference when it hasn't been created yet?

Comment: Then instead of "_order.Invoice" write a _order.CreateInvoice() method, that will return a new InvoiceData. I've updated the answer above.

If you action is named "Create_Invoice_Action" you should have a "new InvoiceData" command somewhere, do you agree? :)

Do you understand that the View.CurrentObject is an Order, and that's why the code you posted is wrong? Understanding those concepts is important before moving forward.